# efficient switch statement when using enums

Tags: c, enums, switch-statement, processing-efficiency

I have an enum and a switch statement using some of the enum entries but not all and they are currently out of order too, i.e. I have the following:

```
enum prot_tun_stat_e    {
    STAT_A = 0,     
    STAT_B,     
    STAT_C, 
    STAT_D,
    STAT_E,
    STAT_F, //5
    STAT_G,
    STAT_H,
    STAT_I,
    STAT_Y,
    STAT_K,     //10
    STAT_COUNT      //must be last
} __attribute__((packed));
```

and then I have a switch using the following entries:

```
switch(var) {
case C:
break;
case D:
break
case F:
break
case G:
break
default
}
```

and I was wondering if I better rearranged the items in the enum to be `C=1,D=2,F=3&G=4` ? Would that be more efficient?

Thanks,
Ron

Platform: `PowerPC`, compiler `diab`

Comment: You want to know if testing `var` against the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 would be more efficient than testing it against the numbers 2, 3, 5 and 6? I would be very surprised if it made the tiniest bit of difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the compiler can determine that the parameter to the switch statement is limited to a small number then it can create a [jump table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table).  This table will take up less room if the values are contiguous but the difference between 4 entries or the 10 required is unlikely to matter. (And note that 0-3 is a better range than 1-4 - although the compiler can deal with this by jumping to offset `n - 1`).

You can check the output of the compiler to see if a jump table is being created (assuming you can read assembly!).  And of course the answer to all performance questions: profile it!

Answer (score 4):

I can't talk about the `diab` compiler, because I'm not familiar with it, but an optimizing compiler will most likely create a *jump table* for a `switch` statement over an `enum`. So the order wouldn't matter. Having said that, you shouldn't worry about such trivial things. Correct me if I misunderstood your question.